# How to fix the maven error The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, maven

When I check on maven's version on a virtual environment, I get the following errors:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

However, I am able to print maven's version outside of virtual environment

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T00:58:13-07:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home:  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I have used set in ~/.bash_profile

```
set JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk
set PATH=$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin:$PATH
```

I don't understand the error as JAVA_HOME is pointing to a JDK and not a JRE? Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not correct:

> ```
> set JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk
> ```

Notice that the output of `mvn` tells you the location of Java home is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`.
So the location of the JDK home is probably `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home`.

Secondly, you need to `export` the variable, not just `set` it.

Write like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home
```

After you update your `~/.bash_profile`,
to test that the setup is correct,
start a new shell, and check the output of `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: You are the best. That did not catch my eye, I am able to print it now. Thanks.

Comment: As this looks like MacOS I will add that you can more generically set JAVA_HOME with `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)`. This has the added side effect of placing the requested version of Java in the `$PATH`. This is especially useful if you work in an environment that must support multiple versions of Java.